# bootstrap and jQuery not working properly in sharepoint 2013

Tags: css, sharepoint, twitter-bootstrap-3, sharepoint-2013

I got a UI issue on bootstrap with sharepoint-2013. I had given all CSS and JS file path are correctly, but if i change CDN link from fire bug its working properly(only working in firebug), actually i am confusing why its not working directly from sharepoint. can you please help me anyone?

I have given file path

```
<link href="../../_layouts/15/Site/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="../../_layouts/15/Site/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../_layouts/15/Site/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

CDN

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

CDN working only when I change it from firebug. It is also not working from sharepoint after compiling.

Comment: Have you tried to use `SharePoint:CssRegistration` and `SharePoint:ScriptLink`?

Comment: Check in Resource tab (F12) that , all the referenced files are available ...

Comment: What you mean "working properly" ? Don't load or do not render properly ? Remember that some bootstrap classes conflict with sharepoint css maybe after change with CDN the bootstrap classes override microsoft classes ?

Answer (score 0):

Access the layout directly

Change path to

```
<link href="/_layouts/15/Site/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/_layouts/15/Site/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/Site/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also will be better if you can use ~SiteCollection and ~Site using Sharepoint:scriptLink

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink1" Name="~SiteCollection/_layouts/...js" runat="server" /> 

<SharePoint:CssRegistration  ID="CssRegistration1" Name="<% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/_layouts/....css" %>" runat="server" After="corev15.css" />
```